# Swift 4: Geofire query not printing any results.

Tags: swift, firebase, mapkit, geofire

I am trying to pull down all my location results from Firebase with the help of Geofire. Unfortunately I am unable to do so. I have read through all the documentation with no luck as to why I cannot get it to work.

I establish my geoFireRef...

```
var geoFire: GeoFire!
var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference!

geoFireRef = Database.database().reference()
geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef)
```

I set my location in Firebase with the build in method...

```
geoFire.setLocation(location, forKey: "\(myKey)")
```

But when I try to pull the information down from the database I am unable to do so.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: 
    Bool) {

        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude)

        showGamesOnMap(location: loc)
}

func showGamesOnMap(location: CLLocation) {
    let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: location, withRadius: 2.5)

//ABLE TO PRINT HERE

Swift.print("Starting Query")

    circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String?, location: CLLocation?) in

//UNABLE TO PRINT HERE

        Swift.print("Key '\(key!)' entered the search are and is at location '\(location!)'")
    })
}
```

Here are my rules that I have established in my database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": ["g"]
  }
}
```

I have been debugging for over two days with no luck what so ever. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution found for this ?